# ERROR Error: NG0900: Error trying to diff '[object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: html, json, angular

hello i want to display the states in first dropdown and in the second drodown i want to display the districts of the selected state but it display this error  **"ERROR Error: NG0900: Error trying to diff 'Visakhapatnam'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed"**

here is my service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class StateDistrictService {
  private stateUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/states';
  private districtUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/districts';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getStates(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.stateUrl);
  }

  getDistricts(stateId: string): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(`${this.districtUrl}/${stateId}`);
    // Use backticks (`) for string interpolation
  }
}
```

here is my component

```
// state.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { StateDistrictService } from '../services/state-district.service';
// import { IState } from '../models/state';
// import { IDistrict } from '../models/districts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-state',
  templateUrl: './state.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./state.component.scss'],
})
export class StateComponent implements OnInit {
  dropdownForm!: FormGroup;
  states: any[] = [];
  districts: any[] = [];

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private StateDistrictService: StateDistrictService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dropdownForm = this.fb.group({
      selectedState: [''],
      selectedDistrict: [''],
    });

    this.StateDistrictService.getStates().subscribe((states) => {
      this.states = states;
    });

    const selectedStateControl = this.dropdownForm.get('selectedState');

    if (selectedStateControl) {
      selectedStateControl.valueChanges.subscribe((stateId) => {
        if (stateId) {
          this.StateDistrictService.getDistricts(stateId).subscribe(
            (districts) => {
              this.districts = districts;
            }
          );
        } else {
          this.districts = [];
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

here is my html

```
<form [formGroup]="dropdownForm">
  <label for="selectedState">Select State:</label>
  <select formControlName="selectedState">
    <option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state.stateid">
      {{ state.name }}
    </option>
  </select>

  <label for="selectedDistrict">Select District:</label>
  <select formControlName="selectedDistrict">
    <option *ngFor="let district of districts" [value]="district.id">
      {{ district.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</form>
```

here is my json data

```
{

  "states": [
    {
      "stateid": "1",
      "name": "Andhra Pradesh"
    },
    {
      "stateid": "2",
      "name": "Arunachal Pradesh"
    },
    {
      "stateid": "3",
      "name": "Assam"
    },
    {
      "stateid": "4",
      "name": "Bihar"
    },
    {
      "stateid": "5",
      "name": "Chhattisgarh"
    },
    {
      "stateid": "6",
      "name": "Goa"
    },
    {
      "stateid": "7",
      "name": "Himachal Pradesh"
    },
    {
      "stateid": "8",
      "name": "Gujarat"
    },
    {
      "stateid": "9",
      "name": "Haryana"
    },
    {
      "stateid": "10",
      "name": "Jharkhand"
    },
    {
      "stateid": "11",
      "name": "Karnataka"
    },
    {
      "stateid": "12",
      "name": "Kerala"
    },
    {
      "stateid": "13",
      "name": "Madhya Pradesh"
    },
    {
      "stateid": "14",
      "name": "Maharashtra"
    },
    {
      "stateid": "15",
      "name": "Manipur"
    },
    {
      "stateid": "16",
      "name": "Meghalaya"
    },
    {
      "stateid": "17",
      "name": "Mizoram"
    },
    {
      "stateid": "18",
      "name": "Nagaland"
    },
    {
      "stateid": "19",
      "name": "Odisha"
    },
    {
      "stateid": "20",
      "name": "Punjab"
    },
    {
      "stateid": "21",
      "name": "Rajasthan"
    },
    {
      "stateid": "22",
      "name": "Sikkim"
    },
    {
      "stateid": "23",
      "name": "Tamil Nadu"
    },
    {
      "stateid": "24",
      "name": "Telangana"
    },
    {
      "stateid": "25",
      "name": "Tripura"
    },
    {
      "stateid": "26",
      "name": "Uttar Pradesh"
    },
    {
      "stateid": "27",
      "name": "Uttarakhand"
    },
    {
      "stateid": "28",
      "name": "West Bengal"
    }
  ],
  "districts": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Visakhapatnam"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "East Godavari"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "West Godavari"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Krishna"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Guntur"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Prakasam"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Nellore"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Chittoor"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Anantapur"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Kurnool"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Kadapa"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Srikakulam"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Tawang"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "West Kameng"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "East Kameng"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Papum Pare"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Kurung Kumey"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Kra Daadi"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Lower Subansiri"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Upper Subansiri"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "West Siang"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "East Siang"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Siang"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Upper Siang"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Dhubri"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Kokrajhar"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Bongaigaon"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Goalpara"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Barpeta"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Nalbari"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Kamrup"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Kamrup Metropolitan"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Darrang"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Morigaon"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Nagaon"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Karbi Anglong"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "Patna"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "Gaya"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "Muzaffarpur"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "Bhagalpur"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "Nalanda"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "Saran"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "Vaishali"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "Purnia"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "Darbhanga"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "Rohtas"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "Begusarai"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "Madhubani"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "Raipur"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "Bilaspur"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "Durg"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "Bastar"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "Korba"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "Rajnandgaon"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "Raigarh"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "Dhamtari"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "Janjgir-Champa"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "Kanker"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "Kabirdham"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "Mahasamund"
    },
    {
      "id": "6",
      "name": "North Goa"
    },
    {
      "id": "6",
      "name": "South Goa"
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "name": "Ahmedabad"
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "name": "Surat"
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "name": "Vadodara"
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "name": "Rajkot"
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "name": "Bhavnagar"
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "name": "Gandhinagar"
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "name": "Jamnagar"
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "name": "Junagadh"
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "name": "Kutch"
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "name": "Anand"
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "name": "Patan"
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "name": "Bharuch"
    },
    {
      "id": "8",
      "name": "Gurgaon"
    },
    {
      "id": "8",
      "name": "Faridabad"
    },
    {
      "id": "8",
      "name": "Rohtak"
    },
    {
      "id": "8",
      "name": "Panipat"
    },
    {
      "id": "8",
      "name": "Hisar"
    },
    {
      "id": "8",
      "name": "Karnal"
    },
    {
      "id": "8",
      "name": "Sonipat"
    },
    {
      "id": "8",
      "name": "Ambala"
    },
    {
      "id": "8",
      "name": "Yamunanagar"
    },
    {
      "id": "8",
      "name": "Panchkula"
    },
    {
      "id": "8",
      "name": "Bhiwani"
    },
    {
      "id": "8",
      "name": "Mahendragarh"
    },
    {
      "id": "9",
      "name": "Shimla"
    },
    {
      "id": "9",
      "name": "Kangra"
    },
    {
      "id": "9",
      "name": "Mandi"
    },
    {
      "id": "9",
      "name": "Solan"
    },
    {
      "id": "9",
      "name": "Una"
    },
    {
      "id": "9",
      "name": "Chamba"
    },
    {
      "id": "9",
      "name": "Bilaspur"
    },
    {
      "id": "9",
      "name": "Hamirpur"
    },
    {
      "id": "9",
      "name": "Kullu"
    },
    {
      "id": "9",
      "name": "Kinnaur"
    },
    {
      "id": "9",
      "name": "Lahaul and Spiti"
    },
    {
      "id": "10",
      "name": "Ranchi"
    },
    {
      "id": "10",
      "name": "Dhanbad"
    },
    {
      "id": "10",
      "name": "Jamshedpur"
    },
    {
      "id": "10",
      "name": "Bokaro"
    },
    {
      "id": "10",
      "name": "Hazaribagh"
    },
    {
      "id": "10",
      "name": "Deoghar"
    },
    {
      "id": "10",
      "name": "Giridih"
    },
    {
      "id": "10",
      "name": "Ramgarh"
    },
    {
      "id": "10",
      "name": "Dumka"
    },
    {
      "id": "10",
      "name": "Palamu"
    },
    {
      "id": "10",
      "name": "Chatra"
    },
    {
      "id": "10",
      "name": "Koderma"
    },
    {
      "id": "11",
      "name": "Bangalore Urban"
    },
    {
      "id": "11",
      "name": "Bangalore Rural"
    },
    {
      "id": "11",
      "name": "Belgaum"
    },
    {
      "id": "11",
      "name": "Mysore"
    },
    {
      "id": "11",
      "name": "Tumkur"
    },
    {
      "id": "11",
      "name": "Gulbarga"
    },
    {
      "id": "11",
      "name": "Hassan"
    },
    {
      "id": "11",
      "name": "Dharwad"
    },
    {
      "id": "11",
      "name": "Shimoga"
    },
    {
      "id": "11",
      "name": "Udupi"
    },
    {
      "id": "11",
      "name": "Bidar"
    },
    {
      "id": "11",
      "name": "Bellary"
    },
    {
      "id": "12",
      "name": "Thiruvananthapuram"
    },
    {
      "id": "12",
      "name": "Kochi"
    },
    {
      "id": "12",
      "name": "Kozhikode"
    },
    {
      "id": "12",
      "name": "Thrissur"
    },
    {
      "id": "12",
      "name": "Kollam"
    },
    {
      "id": "12",
      "name": "Kottayam"
    },
    {
      "id": "12",
      "name": "Alappuzha"
    },
    {
      "id": "12",
      "name": "Palakkad"
    },
    {
      "id": "12",
      "name": "Malappuram"
    },
    {
      "id": "12",
      "name": "Kannur"
    },
    {
      "id": "12",
      "name": "Wayanad"
    },
    {
      "id": "12",
      "name": "Idukki"
    },
    {
      "id": "13",
      "name": "Indore"
    },
    {
      "id": "13",
      "name": "Bhopal"
    },
    {
      "id": "13",
      "name": "Jabalpur"
    },
    {
      "id": "13",
      "name": "Gwalior"
    },
    {
      "id": "13",
      "name": "Ujjain"
    },
    {
      "id": "13",
      "name": "Sagar"
    },
    {
      "id": "13",
      "name": "Dewas"
    },
    {
      "id": "13",
      "name": "Satna"
    },
    {
      "id": "13",
      "name": "Ratlam"
    },
    {
      "id": "13",
      "name": "Rewa"
    },
    {
      "id": "13",
      "name": "Guna"
    },
    {
      "id": "13",
      "name": "Shivpuri"
    },
    {
      "id": "14",
      "name": "Mumbai"
    },
    {
      "id": "14",
      "name": "Pune"
    },
    {
      "id": "14",
      "name": "Nagpur"
    },
    {
      "id": "14",
      "name": "Thane"
    },
    {
      "id": "14",
      "name": "Nashik"
    },
    {
      "id": "14",
      "name": "Aurangabad"
    },
    {
      "id": "14",
      "name": "Solapur"
    },
    {
      "id": "14",
      "name": "Amravati"
    },
    {
      "id": "14",
      "name": "Kolhapur"
    },
    {
      "id": "14",
      "name": "Nanded"
    },
    {
      "id": "14",
      "name": "Akola"
    },
    {
      "id": "14",
      "name": "Jalgaon"
    },
    {
      "id": "15",
      "name": "Imphal East"
    },
    {
      "id": "15",
      "name": "Imphal West"
    },
    {
      "id": "15",
      "name": "Thoubal"
    },
    {
      "id": "15",
      "name": "Bishnupur"
    },
    {
      "id": "15",
      "name": "Chandel"
    },

    {
      "id": "15",
      "name": "Churachandpur"
    },
    {
      "id": "15",
      "name": "Senapati"
    },
    {
      "id": "15",
      "name": "Tamenglong"
    },
    {
      "id": "15",
      "name": "Ukhrul"
    },
    {
      "id": "15",
      "name": "Kangpokpi"
    },
    {
      "id": "15",
      "name": "Jiribam"
    },
    {
      "id": "15",
      "name": "Kamjong"
    },
    {
      "id": "16",
      "name": "East Khasi Hills"
    },
    {
      "id": "16",
      "name": "West Khasi Hills"
    },
    {
      "id": "16",
      "name": "South West Khasi Hills"
    },
    {
      "id": "16",
      "name": "Ri-Bhoi"
    },
    {
      "id": "16",
      "name": "East Jaintia Hills"
    },
    {
      "id": "16",
      "name": "West Jaintia Hills"
    },
    {
      "id": "16",
      "name": "East Garo Hills"
    },
    {
      "id": "16",
      "name": "West Garo Hills"
    },
    {
      "id": "16",
      "name": "South Garo Hills"
    },
    {
      "id": "16",
      "name": "North Garo Hills"
    },
    {
      "id": "17",
      "name": "Aizawl"
    },
    {
      "id": "17",
      "name": "Lunglei"
    },
    {
      "id": "17",
      "name": "Saiha"
    },
    {
      "id": "17",
      "name": "Champhai"
    },
    {
      "id": "17",
      "name": "Serchhip"
    },
    {
      "id": "17",
      "name": "Kolasib"
    },
    {
      "id": "17",
      "name": "Lawngtlai"
    },
    {
      "id": "17",
      "name": "Mamit"
    },
    {
      "id": "17",
      "name": "Hnahthial"
    },
    {
      "id": "18",
      "name": "Dimapur"
    },
    {
      "id": "18",
      "name": "Kohima"
    },
    {
      "id": "18",
      "name": "Mokokchung"
    },
    {
      "id": "18",
      "name": "Mon"
    },
    {
      "id": "18",
      "name": "Peren"
    },
    {
      "id": "18",
      "name": "Phek"
    },
    {
      "id": "18",
      "name": "Tuensang"
    },
    {
      "id": "18",
      "name": "Wokha"
    },
    {
      "id": "18",
      "name": "Zunheboto"
    },
    {
      "id": "19",
      "name": "Bhubaneswar"
    },
    {
      "id": "19",
      "name": "Cuttack"
    },
    {
      "id": "19",
      "name": "Rourkela"
    },
    {
      "id": "19",
      "name": "Berhampur"
    },
    {
      "id": "19",
      "name": "Sambalpur"
    },
    {
      "id": "19",
      "name": "Puri"
    },
    {
      "id": "19",
      "name": "Balasore"
    },
    {
      "id": "19",
      "name": "Bargarh"
    },
    {
      "id": "19",
      "name": "Koraput"
    },
    {
      "id": "19",
      "name": "Mayurbhanj"
    },
    {
      "id": "19",
      "name": "Nabarangpur"
    },
    {
      "id": "19",
      "name": "Jharsuguda"
    },
    {
      "id": "20",
      "name": "Ludhiana"
    },
    {
      "id": "20",
      "name": "Amritsar"
    },
    {
      "id": "20",
      "name": "Jalandhar"
    },
    {
      "id": "20",
      "name": "Patiala"
    },
    {
      "id": "20",
      "name": "Bathinda"
    },
    {
      "id": "20",
      "name": "Hoshiarpur"
    },
    {
      "id": "20",
      "name": "Mohali"
    },
    {
      "id": "20",
      "name": "Gurdaspur"
    },
    {
      "id": "20",
      "name": "Sangrur"
    },
    {
      "id": "20",
      "name": "Firozpur"
    },
    {
      "id": "20",
      "name": "Mansa"
    },
    {
      "id": "20",
      "name": "Rupnagar"
    },
    {
      "id": "21",
      "name": "Jaipur"
    },
    {
      "id": "21",
      "name": "Jodhpur"
    },
    {
      "id": "21",
      "name": "Udaipur"
    },
    {
      "id": "21",
      "name": "Kota"
    },
    {
      "id": "21",
      "name": "Ajmer"
    },
    {
      "id": "21",
      "name": "Bikaner"
    },
    {
      "id": "21",
      "name": "Alwar"
    },
    {
      "id": "21",
      "name": "Sikar"
    },
    {
      "id": "21",
      "name": "Bharatpur"
    },
    {
      "id": "21",
      "name": "Pali"
    },
    {
      "id": "21",
      "name": "Dholpur"
    },
    {
      "id": "21",
      "name": "Baran"
    },
    {
      "id": "22",
      "name": "East Sikkim"
    },
    {
      "id": "22",
      "name": "West Sikkim"
    },
    {
      "id": "22",
      "name": "North Sikkim"
    },
    {
      "id": "22",
      "name": "South Sikkim"
    },
    {
      "id": "23",
      "name": "Chennai"
    },
    {
      "id": "23",
      "name": "Coimbatore"
    },
    {
      "id": "23",
      "name": "Madurai"
    },
    {
      "id": "23",
      "name": "Trichy (Tiruchirapalli)"
    },
    {
      "id": "23",
      "name": "Salem"
    },
    {
      "id": "23",
      "name": "Tirunelveli"
    },
    {
      "id": "23",
      "name": "Vellore"
    },
    {
      "id": "23",
      "name": "Thoothukudi"
    },
    {
      "id": "23",
      "name": "Erode"
    },
    {
      "id": "23",
      "name": "Tiruppur"
    },
    {
      "id": "23",
      "name": "Kancheepuram"
    },
    {
      "id": "23",
      "name": "Namakkal"
    },
    {
      "id": "24",
      "name": "Hyderabad"
    },
    {
      "id": "24",
      "name": "Warangal"
    },
    {
      "id": "24",
      "name": "Nizamabad"
    },
    {
      "id": "24",
      "name": "Karimnagar"
    },
    {
      "id": "24",
      "name": "Khammam"
    },
    {
      "id": "24",
      "name": "Mahbubnagar"
    },
    {
      "id": "24",
      "name": "Rangareddy"
    },
    {
      "id": "24",
      "name": "Adilabad"
    },
    {
      "id": "24",
      "name": "Nalgonda"
    },
    {
      "id": "24",
      "name": "Medak"
    },
    {
      "id": "24",
      "name": "Jagtial"
    },
    {
      "id": "24",
      "name": "Suryapet"
    },
    {
      "id": "25",
      "name": "West Tripura"
    },
    {
      "id": "25",
      "name": "South Tripura"
    },
    {
      "id": "25",
      "name": "North Tripura"
    },
    {
      "id": "25",
      "name": "Dhalai"
    },
    {
      "id": "25",
      "name": "Khowai"
    },
    {
      "id": "25",
      "name": "Gomati"
    },
    {
      "id": "25",
      "name": "Unakoti"
    },
    {
      "id": "25",
      "name": "Sepahijala"
    },
    {
      "id": "26",
      "name": "Lucknow"
    },
    {
      "id": "26",
      "name": "Kanpur"
    },
    {
      "id": "26",
      "name": "Agra"
    },
    {
      "id": "26",
      "name": "Varanasi"
    },
    {
      "id": "26",
      "name": "Prayagraj (Allahabad)"
    },
    {
      "id": "26",
      "name": "Ghaziabad"
    },
    {
      "id": "26",
      "name": "Meerut"
    },
    {
      "id": "26",
      "name": "Bareilly"
    },
    {
      "id": "26",
      "name": "Aligarh"
    },
    {
      "id": "26",
      "name": "Moradabad"
    },
    {
      "id": "26",
      "name": "Saharanpur"
    },
    {
      "id": "26",
      "name": "Gorakhpur"
    },
    {
      "id": "27",
      "name": "Dehradun"
    },
    {
      "id": "27",
      "name": "Haridwar"
    },
    {
      "id": "27",
      "name": "Nainital"
    },
    {
      "id": "27",
      "name": "Almora"
    },
    {
      "id": "27",
      "name": "Pithoragarh"
    },
    {
      "id": "27",
      "name": "Udham Singh Nagar"
    },
    {
      "id": "27",
      "name": "Chamoli"
    },
    {
      "id": "27",
      "name": "Tehri Garhwal"
    },
    {
      "id": "27",
      "name": "Rudraprayag"
    },
    {
      "id": "27",
      "name": "Pauri Garhwal"
    },
    {
      "id": "27",
      "name": "Bageshwar"
    },
    {
      "id": "27",
      "name": "Champawat"
    },
    {
      "id": "28",
      "name": "Kolkata"
    },
    {
      "id": "28",
      "name": "Howrah"
    },
    {
      "id": "28",
      "name": "North 24 Parganas"
    },
    {
      "id": "28",
      "name": "South 24 Parganas"
    },
    {
      "id": "28",
      "name": "Hooghly"
    },
    {
      "id": "28",
      "name": "Paschim Medinipur"
    },
    {
      "id": "28",
      "name": "Purba Medinipur"
    },
    {
      "id": "28",
      "name": "Malda"
    },
    {
      "id": "28",
      "name": "Darjeeling"
    },
    {
      "id": "28",
      "name": "Jalpaiguri"
    },
    {
      "id": "28",
      "name": "Murshidabad"
    },
    {
      "id": "28",
      "name": "Bankura"
    }
  ]
}
```

yes i want to display the names of the districts in the dropdown but its displays this error
[drop down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtsae.png)
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5Awb.png)

Comment: can you provide more debug info? for example what's the value of `districts` in `this.StateDistrictService.getDistricts(stateId).subscribe((districts) => {this.districts = districts;})`?

Comment: In the response of states, try to write states.states and try. it will resolve your error, Error clearly says that, you have ngFor with the object which is actually not an array.